How do I sign NuGet package built by CI/CD (e.g. GitHub or GitLab)
I'm new to this, so please bear with me. I couldn't find documentation on my question:
I'd like to build a .NET project on GitHub or GitLab using CI/CD and have it published to NuGet.org.
Is it required to provide a CodeSigning certificate for being able to publish to NuGet.org?
If so, my CodeSigning certificate will be stored on a USB token stick and, AFAIK, the private key must/can not leave the stick.
How would I have my .NET project getting signed using my future CodeSigning certificate on GitHub/GitLab CI/CD? What are the steps required?
